# ASP Menu With Permissions

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is how the navigation menu looks like. Done with HTML, CSS and placed in the master page.

The idea now, is to show/hide the items and sub items based on user permissions.

For eg: a user has the permission for only sub2-2 and sub3-1...etc. So he should not see the other items in menu when he logs in.
The necessary tables and assigining roles is done. I need to apply those to the menu, somehow. Is it possible.(using ASP.Net, C#)

```
ITEM1    ITEM2    ITEM3      
          SUB2-1    SUB3-1    
          SUB2-2    SUB3-2
```

Looking at the asp:Menu control, but seems it doesnt have the 'visible' property for li items.
Basically I am looking for something like an object/control/method,.. which I can loop through, check for each item and make it visible or hidden. Please suggest the best approach.

Answer (score 3):

The builtin menu supports user roles and shows/hides menu items according to roles.

If you need more grained control, you could have your own dynamic site map provider which could potentially do whatever you want - show/hide items based on anything, roles, usernames, location etc.

I've blogged on that years ago.

http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2008/04/sitemapresolve-and-dynamic-site-map.html

Comment: Role will work if we know the profile names. right? The only thing known before hand is the formid. each form or  page is given an id. The user can assign these form ids to profiles. How can I proceed in this case. If incorrect, plz guide a lil more , on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at my code here...

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Change My Password"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/ResetPassword.aspx" Text="Reset My Password"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem Value="AdminOnly" NavigateUrl="~/UpcomingExpirations.aspx" Text="Upcoming Expirations"/>
                    </Items>
                </asp:Menu>
```

In the code behind...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        if (!IsUserAnAdmin(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name))
            {
            MenuItem removeitem = NavigationMenu.GetMenuItemByValue("AdminOnly");
            NavigationMenu.Items.Remove(removeitem);
            }
        }
```

Instead of setting it to Visible=false, I just remove it if they're not an admin.

Edit...
Just realized that Menu.GetMenuItemByValue() is an extension method I wrote so you don't have it! Here it is. It's pretty useful.

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns the MenuItem in this Menu that has the specified Value (case sensitive)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="menu"></param>
/// <param name="ItemValue"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static System.Web.UI.WebControls.MenuItem GetMenuItemByValue(this System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu menu, string ItemValue)
    {
    foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.MenuItem item in menu.Items)
        {
        if (item.Value == ItemValue)
            {
            return item;
            }
        }
    return null;
    }
```

Comment: The user will generate his own profile , each with different roles. The only thing known before hand is the formid. each form or  page is given an id. The user can assign these form ids to profiles. How can I proceed in this case.